# Where would incorrectly named files (rename without specifying the path) be moved to?

Tags: c++, macos, unix

I accidentally made a big blunder:

In my C++ program, I did:

```
std::string oldFilePath = "/Users/blah/somepath/foo.xml";
std::string newFileName = "foo.xml" //Blunder! Forgot to prefix the new path!
int status = rename(oldFilePath.c_str(), newFileName.c_str());
```

I forgot to prefix the new path, and just put the filename (without a path) for the new name that the file should be renamed to. As a result the file has vanished from the old path, and I don't know where its gone to!

Where is the file ? Is there a way to recover it ? (Time Machine is disabled for this folder, so I can't do that!)

EDIT: Where would the compiled file generated by Xcode for a C++ application be ?

EDIT: If you're running the program through xcode, it should be in:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug/

Don't forget the ~ in the above path!

Comment: It was careless to disable Time Machine on a folder where you care about the contents of it.

Comment: There are over a million files that keep getting generated and modified. If I enabled it, my time machine would run out of space very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the operation succeeded (`status == 0`), the file would be in the current directory of the process when it was run.  It is hard to predict where that might be, but `$HOME` is one plausible candidate (maybe `/Users/blah/foo.xml`).  You should be able to find it, either with the `find` command or with Spotlight.

I don't use the XCode UI (or other IDEs), in part because I don't like the lack of control over things like 'where the program is put' and 'what is the current directory when I run the program' (and for the rest because I'm a dinosaur).  AFAIK, the executable should be in a directory underneath the folder where you created the project. Again, Spotlight or `find` should be able to help you, at least if you chose a distinctive name for the program.  The project directory is another place to look for the `foo.xml` file too.